# Intersection of two surfaces, $z=2x^2-y^2$ and $z=4$

Tags: calculus, parametrization

So the usual way to do this kind of thing is to first plug in $z=4$ to get $$4=2x^2-y^2$$ and now just use one of the variables as a parameter. So now i have a choice, should i use $x$ or $y$ as a parameter for this curve. Now depending on my choice the vector function of the curve will be different. Is the only difference between these function is the direction, in which the curve goes? One is say clockwise and the other one is counter-clockwise?

Thanks

Comment: The best choice of parameterization depends on what you want to do with it. Using _neither_ variable and parameterizing as $\mathbf u\cosh t+\mathbf v\sinh t$ might be even better, for instance.

Answer (score 0):

This is just the hyperbola $\;\dfrac{x^2}2-\dfrac{y^2}4=1$ in the plane $z=4$. The asymptotes  have equation
$$2x^2-y^2=(\sqrt2x-y)(\sqrt2x+y)=0.$$

Comment: I do not see how this answers my question?